# Android - SimpleCursorAdapter Throws Exception

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm trying to use a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a ListView. However, constructing the SimpleCursorAdapter has my compiler throw me an exception. The strangest thing is that I've used almost the exact same structure to great success earlier in my application. This is what I'm having problems with:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "      + DatabaseHelper.KEY_AMOUNT
                            + ", "      + DatabaseHelper.KEY_DATE
                            + " FROM "  + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_HISTORY
                            + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.KEY_ID
                            + "=?",
                        new String[]{""+tenantId});
cursor.moveToFirst();

try {

    tryAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.history_item, 
            cursor,
            new String[] {DatabaseHelper.KEY_AMOUNT, DatabaseHelper.KEY_DATE},
            new int[] {R.id.historyPaymentColumn, R.id.historyDateColumn});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here's the instance of the SimpleCursorAdapter that I use earlier in the application (the one that works):

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, phone FROM phonebook", null);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.phonebook_item,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"firstName", "lastName", "phone"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.phone});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly the difference between these two that causes the `tryAdapter` to fail but leave the `adapter` instance untouched?

Comment: why doesn't it works? what is the exception? So better you post `Logcat` output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant be sure since you haven't posted your `Logcat` output, but looking at the column names in your selection, it seems that you haven't included a column named `_ID` in your projection. Any `Cursor` you pass to a `CursorAdapter` must include a column named "_id" or the class will not work.